# Исключение goto в проверке скачивания файла

Tags: php, fileupload, goto

Столкнулся с вот таким куском кода:

```
a:
$url = 'http://link.com/report.json';
$path = '../data/report.json';
if (file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents($url))) {
    echo "ok";
} 
else {
    echo "no"; 
    goto a; 
}
```

Вопрос: как это можно искючить конструкцию goto, при этом сохранить уверенность что файл скачался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://link.com/report.json';
$path = '../data/report.json';
while (false === file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents($url)))
    echo "no";
echo "ok";
```